# "admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...) is not a function" when trying to store data in firestore as json

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the error "admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...) is not a function" when trying to store data in firestore as json and I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

here is a code snippet of what I am doing

```
  // eslint-disable-next-line handle-callback-err
            simpleParser(idHeader + all.body, (err, mail) => {
              // access to the whole mail object
              console.log(mail.subject);
              console.log(mail.html);

              var promises = [];
              var docRef = db.collection("Users").doc("6IzsLbD4r4R5RXdGB5BQy6xq8Dc2");

              promises.push(
                docRef.set(
                  {
                    Emails: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                      JSON.stringify()
                    )({
                      subject: mail.subject,
                      body: mail.text,
                      date: mail.date,
                      from: mail.from,
                    }),
                    //....
                  },
                  { merge: true }
                )
              );
              // eslint-disable-next-line promise/catch-or-return
              Promise.all(promises);
            });
          });
```

basically I am trying to save subject, body, date, from as json inside of Emails but I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciates as this one is driving me crazy haha

Comment: Try to put some `console.log()` and see what's `admin.firestore.FieldValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this with this

```
          promises.push(
                docRef.set(
                  {
                    Emails: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                      JSON.stringify({
                        subject: mail.subject,
                        body: mail.text,
                        date: mail.date,
                        from: mail.from,
                      })
                    ),
                    //....
                  },
                  { merge: true }
                )
              );
              // eslint-disable-next-line promise/catch-or-return
              Promise.all(promises);
            });
          });
```

maybe this will help someone else with this issue my data was outside JSON.stringify(). Make sure you put your data inside of JSON.stringify(HERE) =]